# How to rotate keys for azure log analytics workspace

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

What is the recommended way of programmatically rotating keys for Azure Log Analytics Workspace?

The only described way I found was through [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/workspaces%202015-03-20/regeneratesharedkeys). However it does not seem to be working:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "" https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${SUBSCRIPTION_ID}/resourcegroups/${RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/${LAW_NAME}/listKeys?api-version=2015-03-20
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "" https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${SUBSCRIPTION_ID}/resourcegroups/${RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/${LAW_NAME}/regenerateSharedKey?api-version=2015-03-20
```

The first call listing keys works without problems. The second, trying to rotate keys, fails with error message:

```
{
  "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://opinsightsweuams.trafficmanager.net/api/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourcegroups/XXXXX/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/XXXXX/regenerateSharedKey?api-version=2015-03-20&contextId=XXXXX'."
}
```

Does this API still works? Are there any other ways to rotate the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 01/23:**

I got the feedback from support team.

The [Regenerate Shared Keys api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/workspaces%202015-03-20/regeneratesharedkeys) had a little changed previously, but the doc is not updated:(.

You need to add the parameter **keyType** with value **primarySharedKey** or **secondarySharedKey**.

The reason of the change: previously, when use the api to regenerate key, both the primary and secondary keys are regenerated together. So there is a user feedback that we should update the api and make it each time only re-generate one key.

I tested it, working fine. The test screenshot as below:

[image]

---

Original:

The [Regenerate Shared Keys api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/workspaces%202015-03-20/regeneratesharedkeys) does not work now.

The actual api used is as below:

for re-regenerating **primary key**:

`https://www.mms.microsoft.com/Embedded/Api/arm/management/CustomerManagement/AgentRegenerateSharedKey?keyType=primarySharedKey`.

for for re-regenerating **secondary key**:

`https://www.mms.microsoft.com/Embedded/Api/arm/management/CustomerManagement/AgentRegenerateSharedKey?keyType=secondarySharedKey`

Here are the steps to check the api, and how to re-generate a new shared key.

Step 1.Nav to azure portal -> your Log Analytics Workspace -> Advanced Settings -> Connected Sources -> Windows Servers, and press F12 button to check the actual request(I'm using Edge browser) -> then click the `Regenerate` button for Primary Key. Screenshot as below(And as you can see from the screenshot, the actual request url is `https://www.mms.microsoft.com/Embedded/Api/xxx`):

[image]

Step 2.Since we know that the actual url, then how can we get the token?

The simple way is that you can get the token from step 1, when view the quest details via F12 button, you can also find the token(it's temporary).

Another way is that, open visual studio -> login with you azure account -> create a console project -> then install the package [Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication/). Then write the following code in the console project:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp17
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            string accessToken = azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/").Result;

            Console.WriteLine(accessToken);

            Console.WriteLine("**completed**");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }        

    }
}
```

Step 3:After get the token, you can use the token to re-generate the Shared key.

I did the test to re-generate primary key, and using the tool postman.

open postman, for **headers and url**, follow the screenshot below:

[image]

for **Body**, follow the screenshot below:

[image]

At last, click the **send** button, you can see the reponse is **200 ok**. And refresh the portal, you can see the new primary key is generated.

If you prefer to use curl or other programming language to do this, just follow the steps above, and provide proper `request headers / token / request body`.

Comment: Pretty nice finding @ivan-yang. It appears to be a bit hacky - as it is not official solution, it might change in the future... Anyhow I will use it.

Comment: @Marcin, if it's helpful, can you please help accept it as answer? Thanks. And for this issue, I'll raise an issue to Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks @ivan-yang. If you are opening an official issue/bug, could you post here a link to it? Or at least update the status.

Comment: @Marcin, yes, I'll update you the status of this issue if I get any feedback. And I'll email to the ms team for that issue.

Comment: @Marcin, I just got the feedback from support team, and updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @ivan-yang solution, the way to achieve it with the curl is:

```
RESP=`curl -X POST -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${servicePrincipalId}&client_secret=${servicePrincipalKey}&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F" https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_ID}/oauth2/token`
TOKEN=`echo ${RESP} | jq -r '.access_token'`

curl -X POST -H "x-ms-client-auth-token: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "x-ms-client-workspace-name: ${LAW_NAME}" \
    -H "x-ms-client-workspace-path: /subscriptions/${SUBSCRIPTION_ID}/resourcegroups/${RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/${LAW_NAME}" \
    -d "{\"workspacePath\":\"/subscriptions/${SUBSCRIPTION_ID}/resourcegroups/${RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/${LAW_NAME}\",\"data\":{}}" \
    https://www.mms.microsoft.com/Embedded/Api/arm/management/CustomerManagement/AgentRegenerateSharedKey?keyType=secondarySharedKey
```

**-- EDIT**

it is even easier with az rest command:

```
az rest -m POST -u https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${SUBSCRIPTION_ID}/resourcegroups/${RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/${LAW_NAME}/regenerateSharedKey?api-version=2015-03-20\&keyType=secondarySharedKey
```